# HTTP Post help - iOS app

Tags: ios, post, https, urbanairship.com

I've successfully implemented push notifications with Urban Airship in my app, but I want to make an administrative password-protected part of the app that enables one to send the push notifications from any authorized iPhone with the app installed.
I need a way so whatever i type in a text box is send via https POST to https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/broadcast.
Can anyone recommend or tell me a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSURLConnection` to do this.  Setup an `NSMutableURLRequest` with the post data and other information, and then use `NSURLConnection` to post it and get a response:

```
NSString * postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"field1=%@", myItem];
NSData * postData = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL * myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/broadcast"];
NSMutableURLRequest * request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:myURL
                                                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                                         timeoutInterval:10];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSData * returnedData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                              returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

You can also use NSURLConnection for asynchronous requests. See the [NSURLConnection Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html).